# how to get the crawler run on cron jon?

Tags: python, linux, web-crawler, cron

here is what I have done -
1. Made a bash script for my crawler

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/john/Desktop/xyz/xyz/
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
scrapy crawl abc
```

2. added this to my script

   ## !/usr/bin/env/ python
3. My cron job command 
   PATH=`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

   */1 * * * * sh /home/john/Desktop/xyz/xyz/123.sh

This is a selenium based crawler so it should open the browser and start crawling but it is not working.

output of - `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

CMD (sh /home/john/Desktop/xyz/xyz/123.sh)

What I am doing wrong?why the cron job not working?

Comment: Can you please get error output? Check Cron manual how to make it email errors to your root email or admin email.

Comment: by using postfix? and MAILTO

Comment: This is my favorite recipe http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/03/26/using-postfix-and-free-mandrill-email-service-for-smtp-on-ubuntu-linux-server/

Comment: is there any easy way out?

Comment: No, your life took wrong turn in the point you chose programming :)

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog but I doubt it has useful information

Comment: haha let me do some brain storming in that case

Answer (score 0):

When you run selenium job, shell session requires X. Try running selenium in [headless mode](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless)